# Saving changes from a combobox in a database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox and want to save the changes in the database.

What I want to do is if the combobox is selected and it is true it must run the code below. If it is false it must then skip the code and go further.

The code below is checking if the combobox is enabled. But when I'm compiling it's saying  true when not selected

```
private void Log()
{
    if (kaartburgerlijkestand.Enabled)
    {
        veranderingBurgelijkestaat();
    }
}
```

The code below is saving the data in the database

```
private string veranderingBurgerlijkestaat()
{
    string gebruiker = curMedewerker.Behandelnaam;
    string bekeken = prodermaform.pKaart();
    string tabblad = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text;
    string pat = CPatient.GeefPatientNaam(patient.Id);
    string wijz = "Burgerlijkestaat: " + kaartBurgerlijkestand.Text;

    CDb dcon = new CDb();

    try
    {
        if (dcon.Open())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.loggen(Gebruiker, Bekeken, Tabblad, Patientnaam, Wijziging, Datum) VALUES(@gebruiker, @bekeken, @tabblad, @pat, @wijz, @datum)", dcon.Conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebruiker", gebruiker);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bekeken", bekeken);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabblad", tabblad);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pat", pat);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wijz", wijz);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dcon.Close();
    }

    return wijz;
}
```

Could someone show me a example how to do it

**I Found the solution**

I have made a check

```
private void doCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbox = false;

    if (kaartBurgerlijkestaat.Focused)
    {
        veranderingBurgerlijkestand();                
    }

    cmbox = true;

}
```

Then I used the SelectedValueChanged Event

```
private void kaartBurgerlijkestand_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbox)
        doCheck(sender, e);  
}
```

And it works fine.

I want to thank you all for helping me!

Comment: What do you mean for _the combobox is selected and it is true_? Do you mean _when the combobox has focus_?

Comment: Please post the screenshot. I am not sure I understand the question correctly or not.

Comment: Compile time avoid the combobox selection changes by using the FLAG(bool) variable

Comment: @Steve When I'm compiling it's saves the value from the combobox in the database when not selected. And what I want is when the value is changed then it must save it in the database

Comment: Could you show the code that calls the Log method?

Comment: @Anandkumar What do you mean by using the FLAG variable

Comment: @Anandkumar Could you show me a example?

Comment: @Anandkumar No it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Event Listener, the `kaartburgerlijkestand.Enabled` only check your combobox is enabled to select or not.
Add this line after your  `InitializeComponent();` line of `Form.cs` file

```
kaartburgerlijkestand.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler
(this.kaartburgerlijkestand_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Also add a function for above code :

```
private void kaartburgerlijkestand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          veranderingBurgelijkestand();
    }
```

Comment: It works, but i have a another problem im working with multiple forms. When I open the form it is saving the data en when I click on the next button it's saving that too. What I want is that it only saves the data if I click the save button

Comment: In that case edit your question to make it more clarify. But I can guess that your ploblem occurs because your update to database function is called when you create your form. Look for you called it in constructor and remove if exists